# Firefox browser showing extra space between menu and slider

Tags: html, css, firefox, cross-browser

I am helping a friend with his site and I am using IE, Chrome and firefox as well as safari to make sure the site is multi browser compatible. Chrome, IE and Safari all show the menu to be as it should but firefox adds 10 pixels between the menu and the slider. I tried to find the source of the error using chrome and mozilla developer tools, and I cannot see where it is comming from. [Here is the link](http://laras-bridal.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a negative margin to the div containging the slider resolved my issue.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @AlexThornton i am the author, and that did fix the issue. I am not too keen still what was causing it.